# sed script to remove everything in brackets over multiple lines

Tags: sed

I am trying to use sed script to remove the content of an array in a file. I have tried to delete the content to only leave the brackets (). However I can't get the sed script to work over multiple lines.

I am trying to change the current state of the file:

```
LIST = ( "content"
         "content1"
         "content3")
```

to this:

```
LIST = ()
```

However the sed script I am using only changes the file to this:

```
LIST = ()
     "content"
     "content1"
     "content2"
```

```
sed -e 's/LIST=\([^)]*\)/LIST=() /g' filename
```

I should also mention there are other sets of brackets in the file which I don't want affected.

e.g

```
LISTNUMBER2("CONTENT")
```

should not be emptied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this **sed** one-liner works for your example:

```
sed -n '1!H;1h;${x;s/(.*)/()/;p}'
```

test:

```
kent$  echo 'LIST = ( "content"
         "content1"
         "content3")'|sed -n '1!H;1h;${x;s/(.*)/()/;p}'
LIST = ()
```

if you could use **awk**, this one-liner works for your example too:

```
awk -v RS="" '{sub(/\(.*\)/,"()")}1'
```

test:

```
kent$  echo 'LIST = ( "content"
         "content1"
         "content3")'|awk -v RS="" '{sub(/\(.*\)/,"()")}1'                                                                                                                  
LIST = ()
```

**EDIT**  for OP's comment

multi brackets situation:

**awk**

```
 awk -v RS="\0" -v ORS="" '{gsub(/LIST\s*=\s*\([^)]*\)/,"LIST = ()")}1' file
```

test:

```
kent$  cat file
LISTKEEP2("CONTENT")  
LIST = ( "content"
         "content1"
         "content3")
LISTNUMBER2("CONTENT")  

kent$  awk -v RS="\0" -v ORS="" '{gsub(/LIST\s*=\s*\([^)]*\)/,"LIST = ()")}1' file
LISTKEEP2("CONTENT")  
LIST = ()
LISTNUMBER2("CONTENT")
```

**sed**:

```
 sed -nr '1!H;1h;${x;s/(LIST\s*=\s*\()[^)]*\)/\1)/;p}' file

kent$  sed -nr '1!H;1h;${x;s/(LIST\s*=\s*\()[^)]*\)/\1)/;p}' file
LISTKEEP2("CONTENT")  
LIST = ()
LISTNUMBER2("CONTENT")
```

Comment: thanks for all your suggestions! I should have explained there are other brackets in the file which should be left untouched. I've edited the question above!

Comment: @Sarah92 see EDIT in answer

Answer (score 1):

Another sed solution:

```
sed '/LIST = (/{:next;/)/{s/(.*)/()/;b;};N;b next;}'
```

Here's a version that would not change any block containing a certain string ("keepme" in this example, but could be anything):

```
sed '/LIST = (/{:next;/)/{/keepme/b;s/(.*)/()/;b;};N;b next;}'
```

Since this does the keepme test *after* it finds the closing parenthesis that tag can be anywhere in the block.

Comment: thanks for all your suggestion! I should have explained there are other brackets in the file which should be left untouched. I've edited the question above!

Comment: My script only acts on blocks that begin with `LIST = (`, everything else is left alone. You can change that pattern, or insert additional tests after the /)/ pattern, to make it even more restrictive if you need to. It won't handle nested parentheses (()). (If you needed that, I'd recommend something like Perl and [Text::Balanced](http://perldoc.perl.org/Text/Balanced.html) as a solution.)